# Controlling Music and Video in Python

Tags: python, video, wxpython

I'm trying to write a karaoke program in python. Every karaoke software has basic functionality like seeking in the video as well as modulating the pitch of music by half steps. What are some modules that I can use to permit this functionality?

I'm going to use wxPython to write the gui portion if that makes a difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly you might want to take a look at PyGame - it has fairly robust libraries for handling stuff like music and movies: http://www.pygame.org/docs/

Answer (score 0):

wxPython has a built in media controller, [wx.MediaCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.media.MediaCtrl-class.html), which can play both audio and video.  It has most of the basic functionality built in, like seek, pause, etc.  I've found it very easy and reliable.